# Observables from boson correlation functions

Tags: operators, hamiltonian, observables, correlation-functions

I am studying the formalism of quantum optics in the approximation of a two-level system coupled to a reservoir made of boson in thermal equilibrium. As usual, the latter subsystem is described in terms of ladder operators as follows:

$$
\hat{H}_\text{boson}=\sum_j\omega_j\hat{b}_j^\dagger\hat{b}_j.
$$

Now, if the coupling constants of the atom and reservoir are given by $\kappa_j$, the correlation function is defined as:
$$
C(t-t')=\sum_{j,l}\kappa_j^*\kappa_l e^{i\omega_jt}e^{-i\omega_lt'}\langle\hat{b}_j^\dagger\hat{b}_l\rangle_R,
$$
where the subscript $R$ refers to the average over the reservoir.

My question is about the use of $C(t-t')$ beyond the approximation $C(t-t')\sim\delta(t-t')$ used to compute the master equation of the two-level system: What kind of information can I get from this correlation function? What kind of observables can I compute from it?

Comment: From where did you get this correlation function? It looks like the expectation value of the coupling Hamiltonian squared - does that help?

Comment: I'm following Chapter 2 of Carmichael's "Statistical Methods in Quantum Optics".

Comment: I wasn't actually doubting you, I just wanted to see if you could glean anything from the context where they discussed this function. I'm thinking about transition amplitudes and energy shifts but I don't know what they are getting at